# Polymer starter kit routing issue

Tags: polymer, web-component

I am using polymer starter kit code and get the GUI with **home, contact** and **user menu**. I am using Java Dynamic Web Project in eclipse. So the base url is :

- `localhost:8080/TestProject/`

  When I click home after clicking contact or user menu then it changes the url to :
- `localhost:8080`

I have tried to set default base url in **app.js** file as:

- `app.baseUrl = '/TestProject/';`

  But still the behaviour is the same.

If in **routing.html**, I make change like:
 -

```
page('/TestProject/', function() {
          app.route = 'home';
          setFocus(app.route);
        });
```

Nothing changes. But if I change in  **index.html**:

```
<paper-menu class="app-menu" attr-for-selected="data-route" selected="[[route]]">
      <a data-route="home" href="{{baseUrl}}TestProject">
        <iron-icon icon="home"></iron-icon>
        <span>Home</span>
      </a>
```

Then the home url becomes:

```
http://localhost:8080/TestProject/#!/TestProject/
```

But it should be:

```
http://localhost:8080/TestProject/
```

or

```
http://localhost:8080/TestProject/#!/home
```

Guys where am I going wrong. Or where should I make change to achieve the home url.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try to delete `/` in the begining of the home path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newer versions of the PSK have following section in the `router.html`:

```
// Removes end / from app.baseUrl which page.base requires for production
if (window.location.port === '') {  // if production
  page.base(app.baseUrl.replace(/\/$/, ''));
}

page('/',updateRedux, function() {
  page.redirect('/start');
});

page(app.baseUrl,updateRedux, function() {
  page.redirect('/start');
});
```